Vuejs + Electron - Cannot find module background.js
I am trying to build a win app for manipulating files and folders using electron and vuejs by running npm run electron:build
It creates an app but when i run it gives me following error. im sorry for all these snippets but it was expedient that i provide them since i dont know what exactly is the problem. thanks in advance
Error
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\NewFolder\project\athlete-file-manager\dist_electron\win-u..\background.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1232:15)
at s_resolveFilename (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:123740)
at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:129347
at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:129596
at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:129600
at BuiltInModule.compileForInternalLoader (node:internal/bootstrap/realm:398:7)
at BuiltInModule.compileForPublicLoader (node:internal/bootstrap/realm:337:10)
at loadBuiltinModule (node:internal/modules/helpers:104:7)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:17)
at c_load (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:16955)

i have my background.js
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, globalShortcut } = require('electron');
//const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';


function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    // Add error handler
    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-fail-load', (event, errorCode, errorDescription) => {
        console.error('Failed to load:', errorCode, errorDescription);
    });

    mainWindow.webContents.on('console-message', (event, level, message) => {
        console.log('Renderer Console:', message);
    });


    if (isDev) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            mainWindow.loadURL('https://localhost:3000')
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error('Failed to load URL:', err);
                    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')
                        .catch((err) => console.error('Failed to load HTTP fallback:', err));
                });
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        // Fix for production build path
        const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, '../index.html');
        console.log('Loading index from:', indexPath); // For debugging
        mainWindow.loadFile(indexPath)
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error('Failed to load file:', err);
                // Fallback attempt
                const fallbackPath = path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'app.asar/dist/index.html');
                console.log('Attempting fallback path:', fallbackPath);
                mainWindow.loadFile(fallbackPath)
                    .catch((err) => console.error('Fallback also failed:', err));
            });
    }

    // Optional: Enable DevTools in development
    if (isDev) {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }

    // Create the application menu
    const template = [
        {
            label: 'File',
            submenu: [
                { role: 'quit' }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'View',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Analytics',
                    click: () => mainWindow.webContents.send('show-analytics')
                },
                {
                    label: 'Scan History',
                    click: () => mainWindow.webContents.send('show-history')
                },
                { role: 'toggleDevTools' }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'Settings',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Keyboard Shortcuts',
                    click: () => mainWindow.webContents.send('show-shortcuts')
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

    // Register global shortcuts
    globalShortcut.register('Right', () => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('shortcut', 'same-athlete');
    });

    globalShortcut.register('Down', () => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('shortcut', 'new-athlete');
    });

    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+R', () => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('shortcut', 'reset');
    });
}

// Add before app.whenReady()
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors');

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);


app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

// Clean up shortcuts when quitting
app.on('will-quit', () => {
    globalShortcut.unregisterAll();
});

package.json
{
  "name": "athlete-file-manager",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "dev": "npm run serve",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "generate-certs": "node ssl/create-certificates.js",
    "server": "node athlete-file-manager-backend/server.js",
    "start": "npm run generate-certs && concurrently \"npm run server\" \"vue-cli-service serve\" \"wait-on https://localhost:3000 && cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron .\"",
    "setup": "npm install && npm run generate-certs",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:dev": "electron .",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w yourmodulename",
    "clean": "rimraf dist_electron",
    "build:clean": "npm run clean && npm run electron:build"
  },
  "main": "src/background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@vueuse/core": "^11.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "html5-qrcode": "^2.3.8",
    "pinia": "^2.2.4",
    "selfsigned": "^2.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.8.0",
    "vue": "^3.5.12",
    "vue-router": "^4.4.5",
    "webpack": "^5.95.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^7.5.0",
    "@types/electron": "^1.6.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "concurrently": "^9.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "electron": "^33.0.2",
    "electron-builder": "^25.1.8",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.7.1",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.1.1",
    "wait-on": "^8.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^6.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}

vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'src/background.js'
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser',
        Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
      }),
    ],
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
        fs: false,
        stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
        buffer: require.resolve("buffer/"),
        events: require.resolve("events/"),
        util: require.resolve("util/"),
        assert: require.resolve("assert/"),
        crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      },
      alias: {
        process: "process/browser"
      }
    }
  },

  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: 'src/electron/preload.js',
      mainProcessFile: 'src/background.js',
      builderOptions: {
        productName: 'Athlete File Manager',
        appId: 'com.athlete.filemanager',
        directories: {
          output: 'dist_electron',
          buildResources: 'build'
        },
        files: [
          "dist/**/*",
          "src/electron/**/*"
        ],
        win: {
          target: ['nsis'],
          icon: 'public/favicon.ico' // Make sure this path is correct
        },
        mac: {
          target: ['dmg']
        }
      }
    }
  },

  devServer: {
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/key.pem')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/cert.pem')),
      //ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl/cert.pem'))
    },
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://localhost:5000',
        secure: false, // Allow self-signed certificates
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api': ''
        }
      },
      '/socket.io': {
        target: 'https://localhost:5000',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false, // Allow self-signed certificates
      }
    },
    client: {
      webSocketURL: {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        pathname: '/ws',
        password: '',
        port: 3000,
        protocol: 'ws',
      },
      overlay: {
        errors: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    },
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization'
    },
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
});

here is my project structure
athlete-file-manager/
├── athlete-file-manager-backend/
│   ├── node_modules/
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── server.js
├── dist_electron/
├── node_modules/
├── public/
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
├── src/
│   ├── assets/
│   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   └── main.css
│   ├── components/
│   │   ├── BulkEntryDialog.vue
│   │   ├── DataEntry.vue
│   │   ├── ExportDialog.vue
│   │   ├── FileRename.vue
│   │   ├── ScanAnalytics.vue
│   │   ├── ScanHistory.vue
│   │   ├── SearchDialog.vue
│   │   └── SecurityWarning.vue
│   ├── composables/
│   │   └── useCameraIntegration.js
│   ├── electron/
│   │   └── preload.js
│   ├── router/
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── services/
│   │   ├── apiService.js
│   │   ├── exportService.js
│   │   ├── fileRenameService.js
│   │   ├── fileService.js
│   │   └── websocket.js
│   ├── stores/
│   │   ├── athleteStore.js
│   │   └── fileRenameStore.js
│   ├── views/
│   │   ├── Home.vue
│   │   App.vue
│   ├── axios.js
│   ├── main.js
│   └── polyfills.js
│   └── background.js
├── ssl/
│   ├── cert.pem
│   ├── create-certificates.js
│   └── key.pem
├── .env
├── .eslintrc.js
├── .gitignore
├── babel.config.js
├── jsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
└── vue.config.js


your dist_electron according to your project structure is empty. Is it?

@JaromandaX, yes normally that dist_electron directory doesnt exist, it is only generated when i run the build

and the "missing file" ... is it there?

@JaromandaX, u can see from my package.json that i have set it "main": "src/background.js", but when i when i run the exe file created by electron after the build i get that error at the top there that it cant find background.js file

so, the missing file, is not there. What process (compile? build? whatever) is responsible for populating that dist_electron folder?
